# MySQL INTO OUTFILE override existing file?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, into-outfile

I've written a big sql script that creates a CSV file. I want to call a cronjob every night to create a fresh CSV file and have it available on the website.

Say for example I'm store my file in '/home/sites/example.com/www/files/backup.csv'

and my SQL is

```
SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '/home/sites/example.com/www/files/backup.csv'
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
  FROM ( ....
```

MySQL gives me an error when the file already exists

> File '/home/sites/example.com/www/files/backup.csv' already exists

Is there a way to make MySQL overwrite the file?

I could have PHP detect if the file exists and delete it before creating it again but it would be more succinct if I can do it directly in MySQL.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

No, there's no way to overwrite it. From the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html):

> file_name cannot be an existing file, which among other things prevents files such as /etc/passwd and database tables from being destroyed.

It might be a better idea to use a different filename each night, as having multiple backups means you can recover from problems that have existed for more than a day. You could then maintain a symlink that always points at the latest complete csv.

Comment: cheers, thought i might not be able. agh well. Its not quite a backup its more a user accessable backup.  Backups are done seperately.  Still, food for thought.

Comment: Have you checked out the linux *logrotate* tool?

Answer (score 9):

Why not `rm -f /home/sites/example.com/www/files/backup.csv` in the script ran by cron?

You can run this from inside mysql. Just escape to the shell with `\!`
For example:

`Mysql> \! rm -f /home/sites/example.com/www/files/backup.csv`

Comment: yea I can do that but it would be neater to do it in MySQL because loops through many databases and creates 100s of files. Looks like i may have to do it in PHP though.

Comment: I went through this exact same process of trying to find a way and the conclusion was that you can't, as the docs mention, for security.

Comment: I've tried this.. but MySQL response was: "rm: cannot remove `/tmp/my-report-2013-10.csv': Operation not permitted" .. file permissions are 666. any thoughts?

Comment: i like it, saves me having an additional cron.

Comment: executing `\! whoami` shows that user commands are executed with the user who started the mysql client, not the server. so, this user cannot delete the file; we get the error `rm: cannot remove `...': Operation not permitted`

Answer (score 3):

For a job like this I would place it into a bash file, delete the file

```
#!/bin/bash
rm /path/to/backup.csv
./backup_sql_query.sh  <<-- This contains the script to backup to CSV.
```

The better option is to actually add a timestamp though.  Disk space isn't expensive in this day and age.

Comment: no not expensive, just awkward to update the HTML link to the new file every day.  Possible, yes but probably more work than it needs. thanks.

Comment: just `ln` the `backup.csv` to the latest and greatest version as soon as it's been made - make new version, rm backup.csv, ln newversion backup.csv -- ta-da, you're done.

Comment: yea i like the ln -s idea. hmm

Answer (score 3):

There is no way.

Only one possible you can procedure with dynamic statement.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE export_dynamic(IN file_name char(64)) 
BEGIN 
set @myvar = concat('SELECT * INTO OUTFILE ',"'",file_name,"'",' FROM Table1') ; 
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @myvar; 
EXECUTE stmt1; 
Deallocate prepare stmt1; 
END;
```

Answer (score 2):

3 steps to do this right.
Your backup will be executed every night while you sleep (or not)

STEP 1 : Create a stored procedure for your SQL

```
CREATE PROCEDURE backupCSV()
SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '/home/sites/example.com/www/files/backup.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM ( ....
```

STEP 2 : Create a script "/home/backupCSV.sh" to delete old file and call the stored procedure

```
echo "$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %T") START MAINTENANCE SCRIPT "
rm /home/sites/example.com/www/files/backup.csv
echo "$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %T")    SUCCESS >> Old file deleted"
mysql --user=[user] --password=[password] [dataBaseName] --execute="CALL backupCSV();"
echo "$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %T")    SUCCESS >> New file created"
echo "$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %T") END MAINTENANCE SCRIPT "
```

STEP 3 : Update Crontab to execute the script everyday

```
# m h dom mon dow user  command

 0   3  * * *   root    sh -x /home/backupCSV.sh
```

STEP 4 (optionnal) :   thanks me ;)

Answer (score 0):

Simply escape to a shell from within mysql and execute a rm command to remove the file before you attempt to write it. For example:

```
Mysql> \\! rm -f /home/sites/example.com/www/files/backup.csv
```

Comment: Tried this and got "rm: cannot remove ‘/tmp/blah.User.csv’: Operation not permitted"

Answer (score 0):

old question.. but there is an option OVERWRITE ON that you can add to the statement

```
SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '/home/sites/example.com/www/files/backup.csv'
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' OVERWRITE ON
...
```

Comment: I've tested `OVERWRITE ON` with both MySQL 8.0 and MariaDB 10.3, both give "ERROR 1064 (42000) ... You have an error in your SQL syntax;". I also can't find mention of `OVERWRITE ON` in the documentation. So, which version / fork of MySQL supports this option?

Comment: Looks like Amazon RDS has the `OVERWRITE ON` option (when saving to S3 bucket): https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Integrating.SaveIntoS3.html

Comment: Correct.. sorry.. I'm using Amazon Rds (Aurora)