# How to overwrite the existing CSV file with new file while export from MYSQL

Tags: mysql, csv

I have to export the MySQL table data into CSV file for every 5 minutes with same file location and file name.
I run the following query to export:

```
SELECT *  INTO OUTFILE ' c:/newfolder/matrix.csv ' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' FROM tablename
```

When I export the data, first time it exported correctly, but second time it shows the error "SQL Error(1086) File:' c:/newfolder/matrix.csv ' already exists". I need to overwrite the existing file.

Can any one help to solve this problem?

Comment: Not being able to overwrite is a security feature intended to prevent anyone who gains database access from deleting important files. If you want to do this you're likely going to have to make a shell command to do it by using `\! rm 'my_file.csv'`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL INTO OUTFILE overide existing file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/960627/mysql-into-outfile-overide-existing-file)

Comment: Backup every 5 minutes?  Maybe binary logging with 24-hour backup would be better?  (easily use a date-time stamp on the files, and delete extra files as needed to free up space in a script or cron job)  PS - If you want to edit your own post, I suggest logging in with the account that made the original post.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using a `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE` statement.

According to [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select-into.html) the file cannot exists or the statement will fail:

> The SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE 'file_name' form of SELECT writes the selected rows to a file. The file is created on the server host, so you must have the FILE privilege to use this syntax. file_name cannot be an existing file...

Use a file with a mysqldump instead and put in crontab

```
*/5 * * * * /path/to/your/file/backup.sh
```