# How to delete (Before executing SQL) a file which is created from MySQL INTO OUTFILE?

Tags: mysql

I have created one file from the **MYSQL syntax INTO OUTFILE**.
then file has been created successfully on my given **Target (/var/lib/mysql-files/)**.

**When I execute SQL first time** then created one file from the MYSQL syntax INTO OUTFILE.
this file has been created on my given target (/var/lib/mysql-files/).

**When I execute SQL for the second time**, this error messages display me.

**Error messages:**

```
MySQL said: #1086 - File '/var/lib/mysql-files/testCsvFile.csv' already exists
```

**Execute SQL is**:

```
SELECT idClient,
   idUser
FROM clients_salespeople
INTO OUTFILE '/var/lib/mysql-files/testCsvFile.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '
'
```

**Expected Result**
I want this, **whenever SQL is executed, then first remove the file (testCsvFile) using SQL**, which is already created on the target (/var/lib/mysql-files/).

How can we do this? please Share your good experiences with me.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/960627/mysql-into-outfile-override-existing-file/960681

Comment: Does not help above link.we do not want to override the file. we want to delete the file before executing the SQL.